# How to auto fill text area created in Fireworks?

Tags: html, css, html-table, fireworks

I created a header using Adobe Fireworks and sliced an area for text and html code. Within that area I am placing a search bar but need it to fit properly without expanding because that ruins the background. I have been trying to use div tags that fill the parent but still it expands the area. How might I get only the cell filled, no more?

```
<td rowspan="2" colspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    *AREA WHERE I WANT TO PLACE CODE WITHOUT EXPANSION*
</td>
```

Example with search bar:

```
<td rowspan="2" colspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
     <select style="float:left;">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
            <form style="float:right;">
                <textarea style="width:100%; height=50%; resize:none;" cols="0" rows="0"></textarea>
            </form>
   </td>
```

Comment: Could you post a link to an example?

Comment: Fireworks slices to tables? >.<

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the overflow.

Scroll

```
<td rowspan="2" colspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="overflow:scroll;">
    *AREA WHERE I WANT TO PLACE CODE WITHOUT EXPANSION*
</td>
```

Hide

```
<td rowspan="2" colspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="overflow:hidden;">
    *AREA WHERE I WANT TO PLACE CODE WITHOUT EXPANSION*
</td>
```